# How to iterate an object retrieved by Fetch API in VueJS?

Tags: loops, vue.js, fetch, vuetify.js

I have a data Object resulting by Fetch:

```
   data () {
      return {
        show: true,
        interval: {},
        dadosCliente: {},
        radio: ''
      }

 fetchNome() {
          fetch('http://localhost:3000/pessoas/'+this.$store.state.cpf)
             .then(response => response.json())
             .then(data => {
                this.dadosCliente = data             
                this.show = false;
             });
      }
```

Output dadosCliente:

```
[{'nome':'Paulo'},{'nome':'Marcos'},{'nome':'Victor'}]
```

When I try to iterate v-for in v-radio (vuetify) I receive message saying which item is not declared.

```
<v-radio-group v-model="radio" mandatory> 
      <v-radio :v-for="item in dadosCliente" :key="item.nome" :label="`${item.nome}`"></v-radio>
</v-radio-group>
```

Speding a time reading some articles, posts, but I couldnt finish it. Anyone can help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use binding sign `:` with directives like `v-if` or `v-for` it should be like:

```
v-for="item in dadosCliente"
```

Answer (score 1):

Removing the : will make it work...
To add on ..since you are iterating an array, instead of binding the nome to the key, you can do something like this

```
<v-radio-group v-model="radio" mandatory> 
      <v-radio :v-for="(item,index) in dadosCliente" :key="index" :label="`${item.nome}`"></v-radio>
</v-radio-group>
```

In this way, you can even handle objects with redundant nome values.